# How to integrate remote signing in Debian packaging workflow?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, gnupg

My GPG key resides on my local box (A).  I also have access to a number of shared hosts (B1, B2, etc.) that I use to build Debian and Ubuntu packages.  I don't want to put my GPG secret key there.

I want to create signed Debian/Ubuntu packages on B1, B2, etc.  Signing those packages is usually part of existing scripts like `dpkg-buildpackage` or `backportpackage`.  While they often offer to not sign a package or a file, having the signing be a part of the process has the advantage that the workflow is not broken and no steps are skipped.

So I need to, when the packaging script on B1, B2, etc. requests to, sign the file from my local box A for example via `sshfs`.  My dumb idea would be to set `$DEBSIGN_PROGRAM` to a script that prints its arguments to the console and then waits for `RET`.  I would then transfer/`sshfs` the referenced file, execute the amended command line on my local box and transfer the modified/added files back to the remote host.

However I have grown to find that for every problem, Debian usually has a pre-existing solution.  Is there one for this type of workflow where the GPG secret key does not reside on the hosts where the packages are built?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have to find a complex solution anyway. You have to trust the machine you're building on, anyway. If you don't trust it, don't use it to build software you're distributing. Additionally, use subkeys. If you realize there was/might be a problem with a given machine, revoke it and create a new one. Juggling multiple signing subkeys is not a problem at all.

Comment: @JensErat: If someone were to manipulate the packages I was building, at worst he could manipulate those (few) which I erroneously signed.  If I lose a key, he could sign everything.  I will look into signing subkeys, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the package "dpkg-sig". You install it locally and on the remote machine, then just pass it the path to the .changes file that shall be signed. The man page gives an example: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg-sig.1.html.